# How to test against current bar date in Pine Script 5?

Tags: date, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a chart I use with a daily timeframe. I would like to draw vertical lines on specific days and I am trying to design a test to check the date of the "current" bar:

```
var current = timestamp(year, month,dayofmonth,0,0,0)
var against = timestamp(2023, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0)

var okDate = (current == against)

str = "Current: " + str.tostring(current) + "\n" + "Against: " + str.tostring(against)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index + 5, high + 5, text=str, color = color.lime,
    style=label.style_label_lower_left, textalign = text.align_left, size=size.normal)
```

Unfortunately, the timestamp values differ by (at least) a factor 10, which does not make sense:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pinescript it is pretty confusing, but the year, month and so on ... are in the `exchange` timezone (for example the timezone of GBPUSD from OANDA) which is not the same as the timezone you select for your chart.
So I think you write `timestamp(2023, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0)` thinking of your timezone and you try to compare it against the exchange timezone, which gives you this difference.

Comment: Ok. Do you know what a solution might be?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
okDate = (year(time) == 2023) and (month(time) == 5) and (dayofmonth(time) == 11)
```